# datetime to database using sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am currently trying to use a user inputted datetime to subtract a start time of one task from an end time of the task, but I am having problems using the inputted time.
can you use datetime for just hours, minutes, and seconds, or can you only start with dates? Here is what i tried:

```
import sqlite3
import datetime
connection = sqlite3.connect('random.db')
c = connection.cursor()
count=c.execute('select * from table1')
records = c.fetchall()
for row in records:
    print(row[0])
    print(row[1])
    print(row[2])

print(count)
connection.commit()

ans_1 = input('what is your name?(person1 or person2)')
ans_2_1 = int(input('what is your start time for hour?'))
ans_2_2 = int(input('what is your start time for minute?'))
ans_2_3 = int(input('what is your start time for second?'))
ans_3_1 = int(input('what is your end time for hour?'))
ans_3_2 = int(input('what is your end time for minute?'))
ans_3_3 = int(input('what is your end time for second'))
date = datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
start_time = datetime.time(ans_2_1, ans_2_2, ans_2_3)
stop_time = datetime.time(ans_3_1, ans_3_2, ans_3_3)
datetime1 = datetime.datetime.combine(date, start_time)
datetime2 = datetime.datetime.combine(date, stop_time)
time_elapsed = datetime1 - datetime2
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(start text, end text, total text)')
#params = (start_time, stop_time, time_elapsed)
params = ('1', '2', 'time_elapsed')

if ans_1 == 'person1':
    c.execute('select count(*) from table1')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)', params)
    c.execute('select count(*) from table1')
    connection.commit()
    c.close()
elif ans_1 == 'person2':
    c.execute('select count(*) from table1')
    c.execute('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)', params)
    c.execute('select count(*) from table1')
    connection.commit()
    c.close()
else:
    print('invalid')
```

it just puts 1, 2, and time_elapsed into the database

If i use

```
params = (1, 2, time_elapsed)
```

then i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/s-wan/PycharmProjects/1/venv/Scripts/database.py", line 34, in <module>
    c.execute('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?, ?, ?)', params)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

I do not know how to solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support timedelta, so you'll have to convert it to one of the types that are supported.

If you're going to be using this in further calculations, probably the most convenient would be the number of seconds: `params = (1, 2, time_elapsed.total_seconds())`

If it's mostly for display, and you don't expect to do any further calculations, you can instead convert it to text: `params = (1, 2, str(time_elapsed))`

If you're not sure, probably go with the number of seconds.